# R function for calculating difference for points in a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to calculate differences between points in a vector. Ultimately, I want to apply to cumulative density function (pnorm) to find the probability that a given point (i) is different from another point (j), and then sum the probability for all
observations where i does not equal j. Specifically:

```
Sum(i != j):

pnorm {
(a(i) - a(j)) /(b(i) + b(j))
}
```

I would like to implement that formula for each observation in my dataset, so that each observation has a summed probability associated with it. Using the following simple example:

```
a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
b = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
dat <- cbind(a,b)

 pnorm{
   (1 - 2)/(6 + 7)}
```

And then repeat for j equals element 2[2,7] to j equals element 5[5,10]. That would give the result for i=1, which I'd then repeat for i=2:5.

Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for `unlist(combn(length(a),2, function(x)setNames(pnorm(-diff(a[x])/sum(b[x])),toString(a[x])),simplify = F))`

Comment: I don't think so. That formula outputs 10 values for me, whereas the idea result should have 5. Not the most elegant, but I think this formula seems to do what I wanted. Definitely would love other suggestions:

`sum <- list()
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  sum[[i]] <-  sum(pnorm((a[i] - a[-i])*(b[i] + b[-i])^-1))`

Comment: it is producing 10 values because you have 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 3-4, 3-5, 4-5 which are 10 values

Comment: Sorry- I don't think I was clear. Those are not the comparisons I want to make. I want to compare:
1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5
2-1, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5
3-1, 3-2, 3-4, 3-5

That is because the comparisons are for each observation